# Vue.js dependency injection

Tags: vue.js, dependency-injection, nedb

In my vue electron project I want to use nedb-promises as a global dependency. I've seen that vuex or i18n plugin will be passed to the construc of the vue indatnce. Will this be possible also with nedb?How I can inject it as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either write your own [plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) or just use build-in [dependency injection](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Dependency-Injection)

Comment: ok, but how I will inject the desired library using the dependency injection?